# Как прочитать данные из хранилища ключей jks?

Tags: android, keytool

У меня есть хранилище ключей и мне понадобились данные dname из ключа. Как мне прочитать эти данные?
Буду рад если подробно опишете все шаги (я очень плохо умею пользоваться командной строкой).

Comment: Надо в Android прочитать jks?

Comment: @VladVetrov не обязательно. Можно другим каким-то способом.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл приложение KeyStore Explorer 
Это GUI для keytool. Смог посмотреть все данные, что мне были нужны.